# Recuperar contraseña mediante correo electrónico

Tags: android, login

Deseo que un usuario pueda recuperar su clave ingresando su correo electrónico, tengo este mecanismo implementado en `PHP` y `MySql` en un WS, y hago uso de el mediante un `WebView` en android Studio. Ahora quisiera poder hacerlo directamente desde android. ¿ Alguna idea ?

**Les dejo mi archivo PHP**

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)){

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);

$sql="select * from Administrador WHERE email_Admin = '$usuario'"; 
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
$error = '';
$succes='';
$rows = $result->num_rows;

if($rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['email_Admin'] = $row['email_Admin'];


                     $msg = "Tu contraseña para ingresar al sistema es: ".$row['password_admin'];
                      mail($row['email_Admin'], "Contraseña del sistema", $msg);
                      $succes = "Clave de ingreso enviada a $usuario";
                       session_destroy(); 

        } else { 
            $error = 'El email ingresado no existe en nuestros registros.';
        } 
}

?>
<html>
    <head>

                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="insignia.ico">
        <title>Recuperar contraseña</title>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                          <center>
                          <img src="santo_tomas.jpg" width="185" height="248">



        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" > 

                        <div id="h1">Recuperar contraseña</div>
                         <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-field" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Email" type="text" ></div>

                          </section>



                          <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-button" name="login" type="submit" value="Enviar" id="button"></div> 
                           </section>
                          <a href="index.php"><FONT COLOR="#004D4">Salir</FONT></a>
        </form> 
                <div style = "font-size:16px; color:#00695C;"><?php echo isset($succes) ? utf8_decode($succes) : '' ; ?></div>
        <div style = "font-size:16px; color:#00695C;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '' ; ?></div>



</center>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: debes crear un API en tu Servidor y luego consumirla desde tu aplicación usando Retrofit. Acá está la librería de [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) Nota: Yo uso [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com), un mini framework de PHP para desarrollar APIs

Comment: Esas librerías son para validación tengo entendido, pero la idea era evitar el webview e implementarlo directamente en la app, aunque igual le echaré un vistazo a Slim

Comment: Obvié la parte en la que debes crear un layout con los formularios xq son obvios. Lo que te llevará mas tiempo es crear la API y la parte de consumirla

Comment: Como comenta @user63659 puedes usar retrofit para comunicarte de manera mas sencilla con tu servidor a la hora de realizar peticiones. Para hacer lo que pides, basta con olvidar la parte de html, y usar únicamente una funcion php que recibe el email, y ésta a su vez ejecute la funcion `mail` y el acceo a la DB etc...